# Spring Security User-Roles are not loaded from external context file under JBOSS 7

Tags: spring, spring-security, jboss7.x

I'm facing a problem on a pretty simple task and i don't know why.
I have a web application deployed under Jboss 7 that use Spring Security to allow access to different users and profiles.

I have 2 different security files one that is a global configuration file which configure the access to public/static stuff and another one that define specifically the users , roles and the paths that are allowed for each role.

Below both configurations:
General configuration:

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.2.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="mypackage.*" />
 
  <!-- STATIC RESOURCES For which security context is not enabled -->
 <security:http pattern="/css/**" security="none" />
 <security:http pattern="/images/**" security="none" />
 <security:http pattern="/js/**" security="none" />
 
 <beans:import resource="classpath*:instance-security.xml" />
 
 
 <bean id="myFilter" class="mypackage.filters.SessionFilter" />

 <!-- setting timeout on success login -->
 <bean id="loginSucessHandler"
  class="mypackage.login.handlers.LoginSucessHandler">
  <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/list/all" />
  <property name="timeout" value="3600" />
 </bean>


 <!-- handler for failing login attempts -->
 <bean id="loginFailureHandler"
  class="mypackage.login.handlers.LoginFailureHandler">
  
 </bean>


</beans>
```

Specific Configuration:

```html
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.2.xsd">
 
 <context:component-scan base-package="mypackage.*" />
 
 <security:http auto-config="true"  use-expressions="true">
  <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/home?err=403"/>
  <security:headers>
   <security:cache-control />
   <security:content-type-options />
   <security:xss-protection />
  </security:headers>
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/home" access="permitAll()" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/dashboard**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/dashboard/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/configurations/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/configurations**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
   
  <!-- form login definition -->
  <security:form-login login-page="/home" 
   login-processing-url="/login.do"
   username-parameter="username"
   password-parameter="password"
   authentication-failure-url="/home?err=1"
   authentication-success-handler-ref="loginSucessHandler"
    />
  <security:logout logout-url="/logout"  invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" logout-success-url="/home" />
  <security:csrf />

 </security:http>
 
 
 
 <security:authentication-manager>
  <security:authentication-provider>
   <security:user-service>
    <security:user name="admin" password="test" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" />
    <security:user name="user" password="test" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
   </security:user-service>
  </security:authentication-provider>
 </security:authentication-manager>

 </beans>
```

The above configurations works perfectly if i put both of them in my web application, the import is processed correctly and the users and roles are added correctly.
For my project i need to move the specific configuration file under JBoss classpath.

To allow Spring security to import the file from the Jboss classpath i used the new "module" concept they have in Jboss creating a custom module which basically has only my file in it. 
The module folder structure is like this:
${JBOSS_HOME}>modules>mycustom>conf>main
and in the main folder i have the  module.xml and the instance-security.xml. (which is the specifi configuration posted above)

The module.xml is like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
  ~ JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source.
  ~ Copyright 2010, Red Hat, Inc., and individual contributors
  ~ as indicated by the @author tags. See the copyright.txt file in the
  ~ distribution for a full listing of individual contributors.
  ~
  ~ This is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
  ~ under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as
  ~ published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of
  ~ the License, or (at your option) any later version.
  ~
  ~ This software is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  ~ but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  ~ MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
  ~ Lesser General Public License for more details.
  ~
  ~ You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
  ~ License along with this software; if not, write to the Free
  ~ Software Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin St, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA
  ~ 02110-1301 USA, or see the FSF site: http://www.fsf.org.
  -->

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="mycustom.conf">
    <resources>
       <resource-root path="."/>  
    </resources>
</module>
```

If i use this approach the file seems still loaded , because the "import" from the general security file does not throw any exception but the security is not applied. So i can access any path without logging in.

Does anyone knows which could be the problem ?
Any tip could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Seems i solved the problem.
My web app is included in an .ear with more others application/libraries and in this ear i had the following deployment configuration:

```html
<deployment>  
 <ear-subdeployments-isolated>true</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
    <dependencies>  
      <module name="mycustom.conf" />  
    </dependencies>  
  <sub-deployment name="somelibrary.jar">
  .....
  </sub-deployment>
  </deployment>
```

While the module was still correctly loaded and dependency satisfied i had the problem described above (with the security roles and user not being applied).

After i changed the deployment configuration to this:

```html
<jboss-deployment-structure>  
 <ear-subdeployments-isolated>true</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
  <sub-deployment name="somelibrary.jar">
  .....
  </sub-deployment>
 
 <sub-deployment name="myapp.war">
  <dependencies>  
       <module name="mycustom.conf" />  
     </dependencies>
 </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

the security roles are correctly applied.

I do not really understand why moving the dependency to the specific "sub-deployment" solved the problem. 
But that is what worked for me.

Regards.